# Custom checkout billing field on email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

In WooCommerce, based on *"[Dynamic synched custom checkout select fields in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725121/dynamic-synched-custom-checkout-select-fields-in-woocommerce/48727517#48727517)"* answer code, I am adding some custom fields on checkout which will be displayed under the billing section on the e-mail confirmation

Here is my actual code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_checkout_custom_fields', 20, 1 );
function add_checkout_custom_fields( $checkout) {
    $domain = 'woocommerce'; // The domain slug

    // First Select field (Master)
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_one', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'label'         => __( 'Art der Lieferung' , $domain),
        'class'         => array( 'form-row-first' ),
        'required'       => true,
        'options'       => array(
            ''  => __( 'Wählen Art der Lieferung.', $domain ),
            'A' => __( 'Hauszustellung', $domain ),
            'B' => __( 'Selbst Abholung', $domain ),

        ),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_one' ) );

    // Default option value
    $default_option2 = __( 'Wählen Sie Zeitbereich.', $domain );

    // Dynamic select field options for Javascript/jQuery
    $options_0 = array( '' => $default_option2 );
    $options_a = array(
        ''  => $default_option2,
        '1' => __( '09:00-11:00', $domain ),
        '2' => __( '10:00-12:00', $domain ),
        '3' => __( '11:00-13:00', $domain ),
        '4' => __( '12:00-14:00', $domain ),
        '5' => __( '13:00-15:00', $domain ),
        '6' => __( '14:00-16:00', $domain ),
        '7' => __( '15:00-17:00', $domain ),
    );

    $options_b = array(
        ''  => $default_option2,
        '1' => __( '01:00', $domain ),
        '2' => __( '02:00', $domain ),
        '3' => __( '03:00', $domain ),
        '4' => __( '04:00', $domain ),
        '5' => __( '05:00', $domain ),
        '6' => __( '06:00', $domain ),
        '7' => __( '07:00', $domain ),
        '8' => __( '08:00', $domain ),
        '9' => __( '09:00', $domain ),
        '10' => __( '10:00', $domain ),
        '11' => __( '11:00', $domain ),
        '12' => __( '12:00', $domain ),
        '13' => __( '13:00', $domain ),
        '14' => __( '14:00', $domain ),
        '15' => __( '15:00', $domain ),
        '16' => __( '16:00', $domain ),
        '17' => __( '17:00', $domain ),
        '18' => __( '18:00', $domain ),
        '19' => __( '19:00', $domain ),
        '20' => __( '20:00', $domain ),
        '21' => __( '21:00', $domain ),
        '22' => __( '22:00', $domain ),
        '23' => __( '23:00', $domain ),
        '24' => __( '24:00', $domain ),
    );

    // Second Select field (Dynamic Slave)
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_two', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'label'         => __( 'Zeitspanne', $domain ),
        'class'         => array( 'form-row-last' ),
        'required'       => true,
        'options'       => $options_0,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_two' ) );

    $required = esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce' );

    // jQuery code
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var op0 = <?php echo json_encode($options_0); ?>,
            opa = <?php echo json_encode($options_a); ?>,
            opb = <?php echo json_encode($options_b); ?>,

            select1 = 'select[name="delivery_one"]',
            select2 = 'select[name="delivery_two"]';

        // Utility function to fill dynamically the select field options
        function dynamicSelectOptions( opt ){
            var options = '';
            $.each( opt, function( key, value ){
                options += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
            });
            $(select2).html(options);
        }

        // 1. When dom is loaded we add the select field option for "A" value
        // => Disabled (optional) — Uncomment below to enable
        // dynamicSelectOptions( opa );

        // 2. On live selection event on the first dropdown
        $(select1).change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() == 'A' )
                dynamicSelectOptions( opa );
            else if( $(this).val() == 'B' )
                dynamicSelectOptions( opb );

            else
                dynamicSelectOptions( op0 ); // Reset to default
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Check checkout custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wps_check_checkout_custom_fields', 20 ) ;
function wps_check_checkout_custom_fields() {
    // if custom fields are empty stop checkout process displaying an error notice.
    if ( empty($_POST['delivery_one']) || empty($_POST['delivery_two']) ){
        $notice = __( 'Bitte wählen Sie die Versandart oder den Stundenbereich' );
        wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . $notice . '</strong>', 'error' );
    }
}
```

My custom fields and their values, are shown on the checkout form and on the order pages on back end. So far everything works great.

But the problem is that the e-mail that I receive does not contain the custom fields and their values.

How can I display that custom checkout billing fields on email notifications?

Is this code correct?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' , 'add_custom_email_format_string', 20, 2 );
  function add_custom_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {
// The post meta key used to save the value in the order post meta data
$meta_key = '_delivery_one';

// Get the instance of the WC_Order object
$order    = $email->object;

// Get the value
$value = $order->get_meta($meta_key) ? $order->get_meta($meta_key) : '';

// Additional subject placeholder
$new_placeholders = array( '{delivery_one}' => $value );


return str_replace( array_keys( $additional_placeholders ), array_values( $additional_placeholders ), $string );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a new placeholder that can be parsed.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' , 'add_custom_email_format_string', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {
    // The post meta key used to save the value in the order post meta data
    $meta_key = '_billing_field_newfield';

    // Get the instance of the WC_Order object
    $order    = $email->object;

    // Get the value
    $value = $order->get_meta($meta_key) ? $order->get_meta($meta_key) : '';

    // Additional subject placeholder
    $new_placeholders = array( '{billing_field_newfield}' => $value );

    // Return the clean replacement value string for "{billing_field_newfield}" placeholder
    return str_replace( array_keys( $additional_placeholders ), array_values( $additional_placeholders ), $string );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It will works.

Then in Woocommerce > Settings > Emails > "New Order" notification, you will be able to use the dynamic placeholder {billing_field_newfield}…

Answer (score 0):

You should first save input value at the database as an order meta [see here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) and then you can get the meta value in email template. All the email template of woocommerce is customizable and located at **plugins/woocommerce/emails/**

You can use this hook to store custom input field at order meta

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $posted_data, $order );
```

Thanks