# Show or hide checkout postcode field based on chosen state in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I am trying to hide the checkout postcode field if a specific state field is selected.

I am following this code: [Show or hide checkout postcode field based on chosen city in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119284/show-or-hide-checkout-postcode-field-based-on-chosen-city-in-woocommerce)

This code is written by Sir @LoicTheAztec and I have change these values

```
jQuery(function($){
            var bc   = '#billing_city_field input',
                sc   = '#shipping_city_field input',
```

To

```
jQuery(function($){
            var bc   = '#billing_state_field input',
                sc   = '#shipping_state_field input',
```

But it's not working.

I want when the state is Newyork then postcode(with required field) display and for all other states it will hide.

Need help.
Regards.

Comment: The state field is a select field, so try to replace  `input` by `select` in both lines…

Comment: Thank you, sir it is working ... but it is reverse because I want to show the postcode only if the state is Newyork. For all other states the postcode field must unset. Please help :) Regards

Comment: Thank you sir, I have done it using your instruction :) Thank you