# Problems with saving the street field in the WooCommerce profile editing page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Based on [Dynamic selectable fields in WooCommerce Checkout and My Accout Edit Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76621372/dynamic-selectable-fields-in-woocommerce-checkout-and-my-accout-edit-address/76623793#76623793) answer, I changed the code as follows:

```
// Settings
function cities_areas_settings() {
    $text_domain = 'woocommerce';
    return array(
        ''      => array( 
        ),
        'Test'  => array( 
            __('Street 2', $text_domain),
            __('Street 3', $text_domain),
            __('Street 4', $text_domain),
        ),
        'Test1' => array(
            __('Street 5', $text_domain),
            __('Street 6', $text_domain),
        ),
        'Test2' => array( 
            __('Street 7', $text_domain),
            __('Street 8', $text_domain),
        ),
        'Test3' => array(
            __('Street 9', $text_domain),
            __('Street 10', $text_domain),
        ),
    );
}

// Utility function
function get_initial_options_arrays() {
    $text_domain = 'woocommerce';
    return array(
        'text_domain'   => 'woocommerce',
        'option_cities' => array('' => __('Select your City', $text_domain)),
        'select_areas'  => array('' => __('Select your street', $text_domain)),
        'test_areas'    => array('' => __('Select your street', $text_domain)),
        'test1_areas'   => array('' => __('Select your street', $text_domain)),
        'test2_areas'   => array('' => __('Select your street', $text_domain)),
        'test3_areas'   => array('' => __('Select your street', $text_domain)),
    );
}

// Utility function
function get_basic_options_fields() {
    extract(get_initial_options_arrays());

    foreach (cities_areas_settings() as $city => $zone) {
        $option_cities[$city] = $city; 

        if ($city === '') {
            foreach ($zone as $area) { 
                $select_areas[$area] = $area; 
            }
        } 
    }
    return array( 'option_cities' => $option_cities, 'select_areas' => $select_areas );
}

// Billing fields
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_billing_fields');
function custom_billing_fields($fields) {
    extract(get_initial_options_arrays());
    extract(get_basic_options_fields());

    $fields['billing_city']['type'] = 'select'; 
    $fields['billing_city']['class'] = array('form-row-first');
    $fields['billing_city']['input_class'] = array('state_select');
    $fields['billing_city']['options'] = $option_cities;

    $fields['billing_address_1'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label' => __('Street', $text_domain),
        'class' => array('form-row-last'),
        'input_class' => array('state_select'),
        'options' => $select_areas,
        'required' => true,
        'default' => '',
        'priority' => 50,
    );

    return $fields;
}

// Shipping fields
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'custom_shipping_fields');
function custom_shipping_fields($fields) {
    extract(get_initial_options_arrays());
    extract(get_basic_options_fields());

    // Modify shipping city field
    $fields['shipping_city']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['shipping_city']['class'] = array('form-row-first');
    $fields['shipping_city']['input_class'] = array('state_select');
    $fields['shipping_city']['options'] = $option_cities;

    // Add shipping address_1 field
    $fields['shipping_address_1'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label' => __('Street', $text_domain),
        'class' => array('form-row-last'),
        'input_class' => array('state_select'),
        'options' => $select_areas,
        'required' => true,
        'default' => '',
        'priority' => 50,
    );

    return $fields;
}

// Jquery code
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_js_script');
function custom_checkout_js_script() {
    if ( ( is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url() ) || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ) :
        extract(get_initial_options_arrays());
        $settings = cities_areas_settings(); 
        
        foreach ($settings['Test'] as $area) { 
            $test_areas[$area] = $area; 
        }
        foreach ($settings['Test1'] as $area) { 
            $test1_areas[$area] = $area; 
        }
        foreach ($settings['Test2'] as $area) { 
            $test2_areas[$area] = $area; 
        }
        foreach ($settings['Test3'] as $area) {
            $test3_areas[$area] = $area; 
        }
        ?>
        <script id="custom-js" language="javascript">
            jQuery(function($) {
                var a = 'select[name="billing_city"]',
                    b = 'select[name="billing_address_1"]',
                    c = 'select[name="shipping_city"]',
                    d = 'select[name="shipping_address_1"]',
                    l = <?php echo json_encode($test_areas); ?>,
                    o = <?php echo json_encode($test1_areas); ?>,
                    r = <?php echo json_encode($test2_areas); ?>,
                    i = <?php echo json_encode($test3_areas); ?>,
                    w = '<?php echo is_checkout() ? 'form.woocommerce-checkout' : 'form'; ?>',
                    s = $(b).html(),
                    t = $(d).html();

                function dynamicSelectOptions(opt, sel) {
                    var options = '';
                    $.each(opt, function(key, value) {
                        options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
                    }); 
                    $(sel).html(options);
                }
                
                function dynamicSelectOptionsApply( val, e, l, o, r, i, f = false ) {
                    if (val === 'Test') {
                        dynamicSelectOptions(l, e);
                    } else  if (val === 'Test1') {
                        dynamicSelectOptions(o, e);
                    } else if (val === 'Test2') { 
                        dynamicSelectOptions(r, e);
                    } else if (val === 'Test3') {
                        dynamicSelectOptions(i, e);
                    } else if ( f !== false ) {
                        $(e).html(s);
                    }
                }
                // On start after DOM is loaded
                dynamicSelectOptionsApply($(a).val(), b, l, o, r, i );
                dynamicSelectOptionsApply($(c).val(), d, l, o, r, i );

                // On change event
                $(w).on('change', a, function() { 
                    dynamicSelectOptionsApply( $(this).val(), b, l, o, r, i, s );
                })
                $(w).on('change', c, function() { 
                    dynamicSelectOptionsApply( $(this).val(), d, l, o, r, i, t );
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    endif;
    echo '<pre> endpoint_url "edit-address": ' . print_r(is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' )) . '</pre>';
}
```

The code adds selectable fields (city and street) to the checkout page and to the customer profile editing page. Although in the profile editing page it shows that the fields have been saved, in the order completion page the street field is no longer recognized (the selected street does not appear). The city field selected in the customer's account is also recognized on the checkout page.

How to fill in the street field saved in the client's profile?

It looks like that field is not saved correctly.Although the profile page shows that it is saved, when re-editing the account, the street field is empty. Where did I go wrong?

P.S: The text was translated with Google Translate